# DevExpress GridControl ColumnAutoWidth

Tags: wpf, devexpress

The question is probably silly, but I spent half of the day looking for the answer with no luck.

I have a WPF view with DevExpress GridControl included (not developed by me). The problem is that when I click "Auto fit" option - it gets too wide with a horizontal scroll. The reason is long header titles, but it's Ok if they are wrapped into 2 lines.

After some searching, I thought that what I need is [ColumnAutoWidth](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ColumnAutoWidthtopic) property. The problem (here goes the silly part) is that I can't find out how to set it! Because of this I can't check if it works at least! There are no examples in documentation, and code autocomplete doesn't show it's presence anywhere. I had some assumptions but they appeared to be wrong.

Can somebody please share XAML (or at least code-behind) example about how to access this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have to remove width element from your columns, and to set the autowidth element of the tableview. the link you posted is related xtraGrid control and it is a windows form not a WPF one, you have to control the width from the TableView.AutoWidth property.

Try to read the following [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6296)

Comment: Thanks, TableView.AutoWidth is what was needed, just setting it to True solves the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Your link is documentaion for WinForms grid. For Wpf GridColumn http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridColumnMembersTopicAll

As I understand you question - you want to fix column width. Try this

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="MyAwesomeColumn"
    Width="40"
    FixedWidth="True"
    FieldName="MyFieldName" />
```

Comment: Indeed, confusing WinForms grid with WPF is what caused all my frustration. I tried TableView.AutoWidth as per Nl Cedar's answer - and it worked!